# How to check an item in a list view programmatically?

Tags: android

Iam using a list item in my application. Iam using the adapter:

```
adapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Settingsmodel>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, listItems);
```

In that i want to check the tick mark of the selected list item manually. I searched a lot. Could'nt find a way to do it. Please help me if anybody knows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list and add a tag every time you clicked on checkbox in your CustomAdapter.

```
CheckBox chkbox= (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(
                        CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    isSelected.set(position, isChecked);
                }
            });
Where isSelected is     private List<Boolean> isSelected= new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

You can do all your work inside following while loop by analysing the isSelected list

```
while(isSelected.contains(true))
            {
                int pos=isSelected.indexOf(true);
                isSelected.set(pos, false);
                sendMail.add(listMap.get(pos).get("email"));

                //                  if(listMap.get(pos).get("email_2")!=null){
                //                      sendMail.add(listMap.get(pos).get("email_2"));
                //                  }
                //                  if(listMap.get(pos).get("email_3")!=null){
                //                      sendMail.add(listMap.get(pos).get("email_3"));
                //                  }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

create your own Adapter....

```
public class SettingsmodelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Settingsmodel>
{
    .....

    public final View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(android.R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(your value);
        .....
    }
    .....
}
```